# What HTTP status response code should I use if a path param is not valid?

Tags: api, http, http-status-codes

For example, if I have this endpoint `GET /students/123/subjects` to response the subjects that the student 123 is taking. **But the student 123 doesn't exist**.

What is the rigth Http Status Code? 204, 400, 403, 404, 422?

Answer (score 3):

Title of your question doesn't exactly match the actual question.

If the student with some *k* ID does not exist, it means that student with that ID was *not found*, and you should return [404 Not Found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404).

However, *not found* and *invalid parameter* are not the same. Your example does not show that path parameter is invalid, per se, it rather shows, that entity, with provided argument, is *not found*.

Use [400 Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) in case of invalid parameter and [422 Unprocessable Entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422) in case of malformed request body.

Answer (score -1):

Most common response would be 404. but if u want u can use 204 NoContent as well. what matters is how do u document your API reference.